# Ruby can't read POST header information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http-headers

I'm creating a post to send to a RESTful web service, my current code looks as such:

```
vReq = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
vReq.body = postData
vReq.basic_auth('user', 'pass')
@printReq = vReq['basic_auth']
```

I am finding that the @printReq does not get assigned anything, and the headers, is not defined. Attempting to read any known header by name returns no results. It appears no header information is getting created when I do this. `vReq.body` does in fact return the postData I've created. What am I missing that will create the headers correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
domain = 'example.com'
path = '/api/action'

http = Net::HTTP.new(domain)
http.start do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(path)
  req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
  req.set_form_data(postData, ';')
  response = http.request(req)
  puts response.body # Get response body
  puts response.header["content-encoding"] # Get response header
end
```

Comment: P.S: postData should be a hash of the attributes and values you want to POST.